# Adding to an associative array in a while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function (`getSSOrders`) that grabs data from an API. Since there is pagination, I am trying to get all of the order data from all pages. Right now my code adds an index to the array. Is there a way to just add the data to the $array_data without adding an index?

```
$page_counter = 1;
while ($page_counter <= $ss_pages) {
    $ss_data = getSSOrders($page_counter);
    $array_data[] = $ss_data['orders'];
    $page_counter++;
}
```

Edit: Here is how I want the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orderId] => 28058625
            [orderNumber] => GS50340
            [orderKey] => 92452700
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [orderId] => 28316205
            [orderNumber] => GS50392
            [orderKey] => 92511383
        )
)
```

But with the while loop, I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [orderId] => 28058625
                    [orderNumber] => GS50340
                    [orderKey] => 92452700
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [orderId] => 28316205
                    [orderNumber] => GS50392
                    [orderKey] => 92511383
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without adding an index"? Can you show a sample of the result you're getting and the desired result?

Comment: No, each Array element is indexed by a number (or String in Associative Arrays). If you want to empty that array while maintaining reference `array_splice($array_data, 0);`.

Comment: Arrays in PHP must have an index, either numeric or text.  In your example, you will automatically get a numeric index with `$array_data[] = $ss_data['orders'];`.  I am not sure why you would want an array without an index, maybe a little clarification in your question may help.

Comment: You mention `associative array` in the title only, can you add more details about that requirement.

Comment: How many elements can `$ss_data['orders']` have?

Comment: @El_Vanja It can have several including nested arrays.

Comment: Then you'd have to loop over it and add elements individually. If it's an array of arrays, it will always add another dimension (what you called adding an index).

Comment: You should be using array_merge for such operations.  But you can also try spread operator like $array_data= array(...$array_data,...$ss_data['orders']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge).

Init `$array_data = []` before the loop and:

```
$array_data = array_merge($array_data, $ss_data['orders']);
```